# URL paths not reflecting url key from admin panel

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls

I am trying to work out why some of my URLs are being presented like the below

```
/catalog/product/view/id/75/s/whiskware-egg-mixer/category/15/
```

I have run `bin/magento indexer:reindex` but the URLs aren't matching the keys which have been set via the adminpanel

The URL key in admin panel is `whiskware-egg-mixer` and when I browse to this path I am presented with a 404 error

Comment: Truncate `url_rewrite` table and run indexing again `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration the URL for your product is not the same with the url key.
Check the settings in `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization`.

By default product URLs have an suffix `.html`. So most likely your URL is `whiskware-egg-mixer.html`. If your are using category paths in URLs there should also be additional entries in the url_rewrite table for your product.

For getting the exact URLs of your product in your system I would suggest to check the `url_rewrite` table like this:

```
select * from url_rewrite where entity_id = [your product id] and entity_type = 'product';
-- for your example use
select * from url_rewrite where entity_id = 75 and entity_type = 'product';
```

This should give you a hint if something is going wrong.

Comment: we arent using a suffix, nor category paths in the URL structure

Comment: And what is the output of the SQL?

Comment: no rows can be found

Comment: That looks like something is going wrong. I would suggest the following test: Change the url key to something else, save the product and see if you get entries in the url_rewrite table. If yes change the url key back to your original value and see what happens. Since Magento 2 does not rebuild url rewrite table like Magento 1 you may use an extension if you want to rebuild all urls, like https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites.

Comment: done this test already no luck though

Comment: OK that's strange, if the entries in url_rewrite are set correctly for some products on url_key changes and for others not. The only common situation when url_rewrites are not created I know is when the visibility of products is set to "not visible individually". But that shouldn't be the case in your situation. I'm afraid you need to debug the saving process and see what's going wrong. If you have that possibility you can start in `Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver` which is triggered on product save.